# How can I find out a whois server for a particular domain?

Tags: whois

I'm trying to make a desktop application checking whois records among other things and I've found a few lists mapping top-level domains to whois servers. They work usually, but sometimes information has to be found on a different whois server. For example while the main server for `com` domains is `whois.markmonitor.com`, `about.com` has to be fetched from "corporatedomains". How do I check which whois server should I query for a certain domain?

Comment: What's the OS you're working on?

Comment: @Anne, Win7, but I have no idea why that could matter

Comment: some operating systems contain specific command line tools that can do the WHOIS requests for you, like OSX and some Linux distributions. They connect automatically to the correct server :)

Comment: `whois.markmonitor.com` certainly **IS NOT** (and never was) the main server for `.COM` domain names for the simple reason that the company behind it is not the domain name registry of .COM domain names. Currently it is Verisign and you should thus query `whois.verisign-grs.com` for all .COM and .NET domain names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two kind of WHOIS servers: Thin and thick.

From Wikipedia

> WHOIS information can be stored and looked up according to either a thick or a thin data model:
>
> Thick
>
> one WHOIS server stores the complete WHOIS information from all the registrars for the particular set of data (so that one WHOIS server can respond with WHOIS information on all .org domains, for example).
>
> Thin
>
> one WHOIS server stores only the name of the WHOIS server of the registrar of a domain, which in turn has the full details on the data being looked up (such as the .com WHOIS servers, which refer the WHOIS query to the registrar where the domain was registered).

`Thick` WHOIS servers are available on the IANA website. For example, here's the IANA record for the [IT TLD](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/it.html).

Scroll down to

```
WHOIS Server: whois.nic.it
```

`Thin` servers are a little bit more complicated. You need to query the main WHOIS server (available on IANA), then extract the referral.

For example, here's the [record for example.com](https://www.robodomain.com/tools/whois/example.com). The response from Verisign (the first `.COM` WHOIS server) returns some information including the `Whois Server`.

```
Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.AU
Registrar: ENETICA PTY LTD
Whois Server: whois.enetica.com.au
Referral URL: http://www.enetica.com.au
```

Then you need to extract the WHOIS server and run a second query.

A list of all available WHOIS servers is included in my Ruby Whois project. [Check the `definitions` folder](https://github.com/weppos/whois/tree/master/lib/whois/definitions).

Comment: To do the second WHOIS query, run `whois -h whois.enetica.com.au example.com.au`.